# Linux Mint 18.3 Repos in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, repository, mint

I want to ask if it's possible to add the Linux Mint 18.3 Repositories on Ubuntu 16.04, So that I'd be able to download Linux Mint specific Software such as WhatsApp and others as well.

Answer (score 3):

Whatsapp is one of the seven applications included in the ubuntu-social-kit snap package which is available in the default repositories in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install ubuntu-social-kit
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible to add those repos.  You'll use a command of the form `sudo apt-add-repository [repository information line]`, then `sudo apt update`.

The question is, whether those programs will work in Ubuntu.  Since both Ubuntu and Mint are based on Debian, the package files in the repo are .deb type, and your installer (whether using `apt` directly, the built-in Software Center, or something like synaptic) will attempt to install them -- but where you're likely to run into trouble is with dependencies.

If a program like WhatsApp is offered in Mint but not in Ubuntu, that likely implies that it depends on something not included in stock Ubuntu.  Start chasing dependencies, or downloading bunches of them from "foreign" repositories, and you'll pretty rapidly wind up with a system that no one can support (because when something doesn't work, there'll be no way to know if it's an Ubuntu component or a Mint import).

A better way to get some programs might be to learn to build them yourself from source, though that's unlikely to be possible for WhatsApp.  Often, however, commercial programs with Linux versions will work in many different distros, as long as they use the same package type.  If you haven't tried just downloading and installing WhatsApp for Linux from the source site, you might find you don't need Mint repositories.